# Why is using PLINQ faster in office interop when in theory all calls get marshalled?

Tags: multithreading, linq, office-interop, com-automation

I am new to LINQ and especially PLINQ. I was playing around in ms office interop and was quite surprised to find that when using PLINQ my code got significantly (depending on the query up to double the speed) faster even though COM should marshal all my parallel calls to a single thread (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2019).

Now I am confused on what might be going on here. I have not run into com server is busy or similar exceptions even on very large workbooks.

```
Dim oWb as Excel.Workbook     
oWb.Worksheets.Cast(Of Excel.Worksheet).AsParallel().Where(Function(x) x.Names.Count > 0).SelectMany(Function(x) x.Names.Cast(Of Excel.Name)).Where(Function(y) y.Name.StartsWith("abc"))
```

The regular approach here is to loop all worksheets and on all worksheets loop the .Names collection.

I know that a Workbook.Names property also exists, this code is just to show a query as an example.

I read that one can use PLINQ queries in Excel (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/plinq-and-office-add-ins/) but I don't know if the same applies for interop.

**My question: can this kind of parallel query be used with office interop nowadays and is it safe to do so?**

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to access STA based Office applications from multiple threads. Otherwise, the host application, for example, Outlook may throw an exception if it detects cross-thread calls. I'd recommend extracting the data from the Excel object model and only then run PLINQ queries or any secondary threads on this data in parallel. And it doesn't depend on the interop technology itself, instead, on the COM server implementation - whether it is STA or MTA.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. Supposedly all the calls get marshalled anyways because of STA - but why is the PLINQ query significantly faster (also I did not encounter any exceptions such as com server busy etc.)

Comment: In addition to my other comment, how would you recommend to extract the Names collection from Excel so that I can safely run PLINQ queries on it?